# Extracting data from RFID reader

Tags: c#

i m working with a canteen management project (in a company). i would like to authenticate users through their ID Cards when put on a Rfid reader. I have surfed several sites but they are not upto what i want.
My problem is , i am not able to extract the serial number from the ID cards put on the Rfid reader. Anyone. plz help me with this.. i m working with visual studio 2012 (windows application) and the language i am using is C#.
My code is as follows:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    RFID = new SerialPort();
    RFID.PortName = "COM1";
    RFID.BaudRate = 9600;
    RFID.DataBits = 8;
    RFID.Parity = Parity.None;
    RFID.StopBits = StopBits.One;
    RFID.Handshake = Handshake.None;

    RFID.Open();
    RFID.DtrEnable = true;

    RFID.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(RFID_DataReceived);
}
private void RFID_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    String data = RFID.ReadExisting();
    label8.Text += data;
}
```

Comment: and what is the problem? is there any exception?

Comment: no.. no exception. but the label8.text remains empty.. the port opens successfully, i have tested it. But not able to extract data ..

Comment: is there none who can answer my question??? i m stuck up.. anyone plz help me

Answer (score 0):

I have never wrote anything based on serial communication, but can try to help you since there is no better option :)

Reading ms docs about SerialPort.DataReceived event (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.datareceived%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) I have following suspects:

1. **DataReceived event is raised on a secondary thread** So, is the event called? do you synchronize threads?
2. The page linked above contains some simple example which prints received data onto console. Please try to build it and run. Is it working? if not, you may have problem with hardware, device driver or device settings.

Hope this helps

Comment: thank u very much for ur suggestion... but again i am facing a problem. my RFID_DataReceived method is not called. Still unable to read the data from the serial port..

Comment: yea i have tried that code .. but no use.. i m not getting a single character as a output.

Comment: if you have nothing on the output i'd guess there are some problems on lower layers (device connection, drivers, config)

Comment: yea but we have an application installed in our pc that reads the data from the rfid reader. but the problem is when we are coding in visual studio , no output. And that installed application is made using the vb.net

Comment: In that case, please try to check if transmission parameters used in the sample or in your program(port name, daud rate, parity,etc.) are similar to those set in the provided application. If there is no place like "tansmission config" in the app, you can try to look what's under the hood using reflector or similar tool.

Answer (score 0):

What I did was to use a timer instead of the event handler:

```
private void scale_com_port_open()
{
   try
   {
       serialPort2.PortName = "COM9";
       serialPort2.BaudRate = Convert.ToInt32("115200");
       serialPort2.DataBits = Convert.ToInt32("8");
       serialPort2.StopBits = (StopBits)Enum.Parse(typeof(StopBits), "One");
       serialPort2.Parity = (Parity)Enum.Parse(typeof(Parity), "None");
       serialPort2.Open();
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
       MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
   }
}
```

I then added a timer that triggers every, let's say every 100ms.

```
  private void timer3_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)//database inserting rfid tag ID
  {
      string rfid_no = "";
      textRFID.Text = "";

      try
      {
          if (serialPort2.IsOpen)
          {
             string rfid_data = serialPort1.ReadExisting();

             if(rfid_data == "") {}

             else
             {
                textRFID.Text = rfid_data;
                timer3.Enabled = false;
             }
          }
       }
       catch (Exception ex)
       {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
       }
   }
```

This works everytime for me

Comment: It makes sense, when one is working with a serial reader or serial device in general, the way you program you application is sending synchronous messages, you send a message and wait for a reply, that is why it did not work using events. If you look at your code, you only get tags when queries the reader using serialPort1.ReadExisting().

Answer (score 0):

DataReceived Event will never call, because you have to call RFID.ReadExisting(); first.
You can call RFID.ReadExisting(); in a seperate thread in a loop and read as long as you got exeption. If  exception will occur then reader is maybe disconnected or something else is happend.
BTW: which rfid reader are you using?